# How to remove bound keys created in xbindkeys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, configuration

I'm a beginner.

I used `xbindkeys` program to create a shortcut to my browser. The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> a while back. I want to remove this shortcut.

When I look in `xbindkeys-config` now, there are no shortcuts shown, but the shortcut still works!

I don't know how to find the shortcut, let alone remove it!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and use this command to reset the keyboard shortcuts to default

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
2. Then kill the `xbindkeys` daemon process with the command:

   ```
   killall xbindkeys
   ```

   and start it again with command

   ```
   xbindkeys
   ```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I used the same shortcut and removed it later.

Comment: i would just kill all processed named xbindkeys